# How to display this historical map in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet

I want to display the historical map(s) of https://maps.arcanum.com within Leaflet
for example
https://maps.arcanum.com/en/map/cadastral/?bbox=1818024.4366235493%2C6140141.1577868685%2C1827115.6656752175%2C6143599.933316773&map-list=1&layers=3%2C4

Btw: this site used to be named https://www.mapire.eu in the past

It seems to be that the TMS-tiles, e.g. https://tiles.arcanum.com/mercator/cadastral/15/17878/11361?v=54 are not able to be openend outside the original website, I just receive a grey image. I already tried to change the referer-header when calling a tile to "https://maps.arcanum.com" but this also just served a grey file

I found one site with hints regarding this problem, together with the fact that the files are hosted by Amazon Cloudfront, but it seems that this hints are outdated: https://github.com/minorua/TileLayerPlugin/issues/28

Do you have any idea if there's a method how to use these Historical maps with Leaflet anyway?